# Consulta compleja en Phalcon (INNER JOIN ) de 6 tablas

Tags: mysql, sql, phalcon

Buenos días.
Mi duda es acerca de como pasar una consulta hecha en lenguaje **SQL** a **Phalcon**.
Esta es mi consulta:

```
SELECT pr_employees.doctype_id, pr_employees.id, pr_employees.last_name, 
pr_employees.last_name2, pr_employees.name, 
pr_employees.bod, pr_employees.gender, 
pr_employees.address, pr_employees.phone, 
pr_employees.cell_phone, pr_employees.email, 
pr_employees.city_birth, 
pr_employees.city_life, 
pr_employees.cost_center_id, pr_employees.cesantias_id, 
pr_employees.afp_id, pr_employees.eps_id, 
pr_employees.ccf_id, pr_employees.provision_group_id, 
pr_employees.bank, pr_employees.bank_account, 
pr_employees.relationship_id, pr_employees.status, 
pr_employees.doa, pr_employees.dor,
pr_cities.city, c.city,
pr_cost_centers.cost_center,
pr_relationship.relationship,
pr_funds.fund, f.fund, u.fund, n.fund,
pr_provision_groups.provision_group
FROM pr_employees 
INNER JOIN pr_relationship  
ON pr_relationship.id = pr_employees.relationship_id
INNER JOIN pr_cities ON pr_cities.id = pr_employees.city_birth
INNER JOIN pr_cities AS c ON pr_employees.city_life = c.id
INNER JOIN pr_cost_centers ON pr_cost_centers.id = 
pr_employees.cost_center_id
INNER JOIN pr_funds ON pr_employees.cesantias_id = pr_funds.id
INNER JOIN pr_funds AS f ON pr_employees.afp_id = f.id
INNER JOIN pr_funds AS u ON pr_employees.eps_id = u.id
INNER JOIN pr_funds AS n ON pr_employees.ccf_id = n.id
INNER JOIN pr_provision_groups ON pr_provision_groups.id =   
pr_employees.provision_group_id
WHERE pr_employees.id = 35523859
```

Les agradeceria me dieran una mano, ya que e investigado y la verdad estoy muy confundida.

Mil gracias

Comment: que onda raulin xD, cual seria la duda especifica? Saludos,

Comment: cual es la etructura para pasar ese consulta a phalcon?............ Gracias

Comment: @YohaBR revisé el SQL y antes de pasarla a Phalcon tenés que revisar por ejemplo el porque le haces 4 `INNER JOIN` entre la tabla `pr_funds` y `pr_employes` este `INNER` podría quedar en una sola línea con un `AND`, revise mejor su consulta.